# Background doesn't show up ( hovering function maybe? )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

So, I have a div with a background image. The problem is that when the page loads, the background images doesn't show up. Although, if I hover over it and then move mouse somewhere else (I have some function that I'll be showing below) the bg shows up. I look with inspect element but there's changed. My css background is strikesthrought and the one from jquery is available, and the same.

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="p1" id="1">
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
        <h2>Daily UI</h2>
        <h4>Click on the name for more details.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: $lgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0.75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    padding: 25px;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 25vw;

    div { 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 1;

        h4 { margin: 0; }
        i {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 5px;
            transition: 0.3s ease;

            &:hover { opacity: 1; }
        }
        i, h2, h4 { display: none; }
    }

    .p1{ background: url("img/1.png") 0% 0% / cover; }
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(".item div").hover(function() {
    var aux = $(this).attr('id'); aux++;
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.1, function() {
        $(this).css("background", "url('img/" + aux + ".png')");
        $(this).css("background-size", "cover");
        $(this).find('*').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
}, function() {
    var aux = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.1, function() {
        $(this).css("background", "url('img/" + aux + ".png')");
        $(this).css("background-size", "cover");
        $(this).find('*').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

Comment: `.p1` doen't match any element in the HTML snippett you posted.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Sorry, my bad, I posted the wrong HTML markup for the question.

Comment: Try to make fade in slower. Or remove this fadeIn fadeOut stuff and try it again. Make a test: change url('img/" + aux + ".png') to green and look what happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code in code pen, and it works all fine. I can see the background image. I just replaced your link with some random picture.

//codepen.io/anon/pen/aYONjO

Try putting width and height on your p1 div, cause, background images need to have height and width defined , in order to show up. Although, you have defined the height and width on .item, and it seems to work for me just fine...

Maybe you'r link is messed up? See if you gave him a right path..